# Arduino switch between define statements

Tags: c++, arduino

I have three serial ports configured.

I want to switch the output of a function to any of these three ports.

Ports have `#define` statements to give them friendly names

```
#define Port0 Serial
#define Port1 Serial1 
#define Port2 Serial2 

String destination_select;
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
void port_select(int selectPORT){

   if (selectPORT == 0){

   destination_select = PORT0;
 }

 else if (selectPORT == 1){

  destination_select = PORT1;
 }

 else if (selectPORT == 2){

  destination_select = PORT2;
 }

}

void mycommand(){
 port_select(0);
 // Prints to Port 0
 destination_select.println("Port0");
 port_select(1);
 // Prints to Port 1
 destination_select.println("Port1");
 port_select(2);
 // Prints to Port 2
 destination_select.println("Port2");
}
```

This doesn't work but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Can you defined how it *doesn't work*?

Comment: stack_overflow:11: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'Serial_')

    destination_select = PORT0;

Comment: BTW `PORT0` is not the same as the one in `#define Port0 Serial`.

Comment: Hi Thanks i spotted that. I typed the code rather than coping it hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok
The answer is to use a pointer:

I found the answer here:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Pointer

I hope this helps someone else.